# Redis queue with claim expire

Tags: redis

I have a queue interface I want to implement in redis. The trick is that each worker can claim an item for N seconds after that it's presumed the worker has crashed and the item needs to be claimable again. It's the worker's responsibility to remove the item when finished. How would you do this in redis? I am using phpredis but that's kind of irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To realize a simple queue in redis that can be used to resubmit crashed jobs I'd try something like this:

- 1 list "up_for_grabs"
- 1 list "being_worked_on"
- auto expiring locks

a worker trying to grab a job would do something like this:

```
timeout = 3600
#wrap this in a transaction so our cleanup wont kill the task
#Move the job away from the queue so nobody else tries to claim it
job = RPOPLPUSH(up_for_grabs, being_worked_on)
#Set a lock and expire it, the value tells us when that job will time out. This can be arbitrary though
SETEX('lock:' + job, Time.now + timeout, timeout)
#our application logic
do_work(job)

#Remove the finished item from the queue.
LREM being_worked_on -1 job
#Delete the item's lock. If it crashes here, the expire will take care of it
DEL('lock:' + job)
```

And every now and then, we could just grab our list and check that all jobs that are in there actually have a lock.
If we find any jobs that DON'T have a lock, this means it expired and our worker probably crashed.
In this case we would resubmit.

This would be the pseudo code for that:

```
loop do
    items = LRANGE(being_worked_on, 0, -1)
    items.each do |job| 
        if !(EXISTS("lock:" + job))
            puts "We found a job that didn't have a lock, resubmitting"
            LREM being_worked_on -1 job
            LPUSH(up_for_grabs, job)
        end
    end
    sleep 60
end
```

Comment: I wish you didnt need a MULTI-EXEC in the first block.

Comment: Yeah, that was only a comment that was left over. But you're right, we probably need one so the cleanup-process doesn't kill anything

Comment: I think there is an issue with your solution, according to the docs LREM is O(N) so it would  hurt performance when working with big lists. It should be preferable to use a O(1) alternative, if possible.

Comment: @MarcSeeger A MULTI-EXEC to wrap calls to RPOPLPUSH and SETEX will not help since you need the value returned by RPOPLPUSH for the SETEX call. Since Redis 2.6, this can be solved using an LUA script.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up standard synchronized locking scheme in Redis with `[SETNX][1]`. Basically, you use `SETNX` to create a lock that everyone tries to acquire. To release the lock, you can `DEL` it and you can also set up an `EXPIRE` to make the lock releasable. There are other considerations here, but nothing out of the ordinary in setting up locking and critical sections in a distributed application.

Comment: Hm, I asked about a queue. This is about a lock. Not sure how to get from the lock to the queue.

Comment: You should use a lock to represent whether or not an item is claimed. If the lock expires, it is now claimable again. Before the worker unlocks the resource, you remove it, then release the lock. That is how I would do this in Redis.