# How to design a scalable rpc call listener?

Tags: node.js, scalability, xml-rpc, json-rpc

I have to listen for rpc calls , stack them somewhere , process them, and answer. The thing is that they are not run as soon as they come. The response is an ACK for each rpc call recieved.
The problem is that i want to design it in a way that i can have many listening servers writing in the same stack of calls, piling them up as they come.

My objective is to listen to as many calls as possible. How should i achieve this?

My main technology is Perl and node.js but would use any open source software for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like any kind of job queue will do what you need it to; I'm personally a big fan of using [Redis](http://redis.io/) for this kind of thing. Since Redis lists maintain insertion order, you can simply [LPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/lpush) your RPC call info on to the end of the list from any number of web servers listening to the RPC calls, and somewhere else (in another process/on another machine, I assume) [RPOP](http://redis.io/commands/rpop) (or [BRPOP](http://redis.io/commands/brpop)) them off and process them.

Since Node.js uses fully asynchronous IO, assuming you're not doing a lot of processing in your RPC listeners (that is, you're only listening for requests, sending an ACK, and pushing onto Redis), my guess is that Node would be *exceedingly* efficient at this.

An aside on using Redis for a queue: if you want to ensure that, in the event of a catastrophic failure, jobs are not lost, you'll need to implement a little more logic; from the [RPOPLPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) documentation:

> **Pattern: Reliable queue**
>
> Redis is often used as a messaging server to implement processing of background jobs or other kinds of messaging
> tasks. A simple form of queue is often obtained pushing values into a
> list in the producer side, and waiting for this values in the consumer
> side using RPOP (using polling), or BRPOP if the client is better
> served by a blocking operation.
>
> However in this context the obtained
> queue is not reliable as messages can be lost, for example in the case
> there is a network problem or if the consumer crashes just after the
> message is received but it is still to process.
>
> RPOPLPUSH (or
> BRPOPLPUSH for the blocking variant) offers a way to avoid this
> problem: the consumer fetches the message and at the same time pushes
> it into a processing list. It will use the LREM command in order to
> remove the message from the processing list once the message has been
> processed.
>
> An additional client may monitor the processing list for
> items that remain there for too much time, and will push those timed
> out items into the queue again if needed.

Comment: So, the pattern is about requesting a RPOPLPUSH from the server that does the actual processing of the messages, but what happens with the other list? Does it get destroyed after it's completed?

Comment: The RPOPLPUSH is just a way to ensure that, if the worker crashes, you can find this out later and re-process the failed job. If the job succeeds, and you remove the item from the temporary list, it automatically goes away (as do all lists in Redis). Thus, if every item in the queue gets consumed, the list will go away, and BRPOP will block until a new item is pushed onto the list (and the list is then recreated).

Comment: Here's a great writeup on SO of the pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8555671/62082

Comment: Your answer solves also another problem, the "being worked on" problem. Thanks.